# Why JavaObject can not be addressed with descriptive programming in UFT 12.52

Tags: java, hp-uft, vbscript, uft-12.52

I am trying to address JavaObject (JPanel) by means of descriptive programming (DP)

```
JavaWindow("label:=some label").JavaDialog("title:=some title").JavaObject([descriptor])
```

I checked existence of `JavaWindow(...).JavaDialog(...)` block and it returned True, but all I did to get JavaObject was in vain (tried different descriptors and their combination like "attached text", "toolkit class", "text") JavaObject did return False on `.Exist(0)` check

[image: JPanel (JavaObject) in Object Spy]

When I added JPanel to object repository (OR) and tried to access it by means of OR everything was fine (mistake on the pic OR & DP highlights in code misplaced, and they are pointed the right way on the Watch panel):

[image: access by OR and by DP]

Does anyone know is it possible to address JavaObject by DP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that works for me now is set of properties: `toolkit class` & `attached text`.

Till now I tested this set of descriptors with `toolkit class` of JavaObject:

- JEllipsisTextField
- JRootPane

Even some objects in sequence could be omitted.